# Trying to create a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW film_list
AS
SELECT 
    film.film_id AS FID, film.title AS title, film.description AS description, 
    category.name AS category, film.rental_rate AS price,
    film.length AS length, film.rating AS rating, 
    LISTAGG(actor.first_name ||'  '|| actor.last_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP AS actors
FROM 
    category LEFT JOIN film_category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id 
                 LEFT JOIN film ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
                        JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
                        JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY 
     film.film_id, film.title, film.description, category.name, 
     film.rental_rate, film.length,  film.rating;
```

Its giving the foll following error :

```
Error at line 1
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

And I don't see any right parenthesis open, your help would be much appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error at line :

```
LISTAGG(actor.first_name ||'  '|| actor.last_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP AS actors
```

Change it to something like :

```
LISTAGG(actor.first_name ||'  '|| actor.last_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP  (ORDER BY actor.first_name) AS actors
```

Answer (score 1):

WITHIN GROUP has an order by clause surrounded by parentheses. See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)